# error undefined reference to

Tags: c++, qt, class, undefined-reference

Hi I have some code that always gives me a " undefined reference-Error"

Eingabewerte.h

```
    #ifndef EINGABEWERTE_H
    #define EINGABEWERTE_H        

    class EingabeWerte
    {
    public:
        EingabeWerte();

    private:
        int A_Ein;
        int B_Ein ;
        QString C_Ein ;

    public:
        // Getter-Methods
        //! Method returns A_Ein
        int getVar_a()  { return A_Ein; }
        //! Method returns B_Ein
        int getVar_b(void) const { return B_Ein; }
        //! Method returns Var_Text1
        QString getVar_Text1(void) const { return C_Ein; }


        // Setter-Methods
        //! Method sets Var_a
        void setVar_a(int input)        {A_Ein = input;}
        //! Method sets Var_b
        void setVar_b(int input)        {B_Ein = input;}
        //! Method sets Var_Text1
        void setVar_Text1(QString input){C_Ein = input;}      
    };

    #endif // EINGABEWERTE_H
```

ErgbnisAusFortran.h:

```
class EingabeWerte;

class ErgbnisAusFortran
 {
public:
   ErgbnisAusFortran();
private:
   int Var_a;
   int Var_b ;  
public: 
   int getVar_a() const { return Var_a; }
   int getVar_res() const { return Var_res; }

   void setVar_res(int input)      {Var_res = input;}
   void setVar_a(int input)        {Var_a = input;}

   ErgbnisAusFortran calculateResults(EingabeWerte Ein);    
};
```

mainwindow.h:

```
    #include "mainwindow.h"
    #include "ui_mainwindow.h"

    #include <QDebug>
    #include <QString>       

    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
        QMainWindow(parent),
        ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);
    }

    MainWindow::~MainWindow()
    {
        delete ui;
    }

    void MainWindow::on_pb_Calculate_clicked()
    {
        EingabeWerte ZusammengefassteEin;        
        ErgbnisAusFortran resultWerte;        

        ZusammengefassteEin.setVar_a(ui->lne_Value_A->text().toInt());

        resultWerte.calculateResults(ZusammengefassteEin);    


           ui->lne__Result_Val->setText(QString::number(resultWerte.getVar_res()));
    }
```

the line : **resultWerte.calculateResults(ZusammengefassteEin);**  gives me the error. Does anybody know why?

thank you itelly

Comment: Does `ErgbnisAusFortran::calculateResults()` function have a definition (implementation)?

Comment: Can we possibly see your ErgbnisAusFortran.cpp/cxx/cwhatever?

Comment: You must not only write .h files, but also .cpp files. In C++ you usually need both.